# How do you handle the distinction between "modifiers" (adjectives and adverbs) and "determiners" in a generic way?

Tags: grammar

I am working on a conlang and am trying to better handle the distinction between adverbs, adjectives, and determiners. Adverbs **modify** verbs (and other things), and adjectives **modify** nouns, but determiners aren't typically said to **modify** anything. But in my perspective, for my conlang, I would like to treat determiners as a form of "focusing modifiers", essentially focusing the context of the the following phrase in some way (i.e. "the tree").

Currently I have the general rule:

- `i`: Precede the verb with this
- `a`: Precede the noun with this
- `u`: Precede the modifier chain with this

However, it doesn't seem like it will work now that I think of it.

For example:

```
I will super quietly run quickly.
```

That really is a bunch of adverbs to the verb `run`, some coming before and some coming after. I think I am going to enforce the modifiers coming before the thing they are modifying.

```
I will super quietly quickly run.
```

But the problem with this is, `quiet` and `quick` are adjectives, *they are already modifiers* before being turned into adverbs! In my lang, it would be something like this:

```
a me i will u super quiet quick i run.
```

But am I going to run into problems with this? Should I be adding particles/distinguishers between adjectives and adverbs or something like that (both are modifiers...)? I.e.:

```
a me i will u super-ly quiet-ly quick-ly i run.
```

Or is it possible to completely know unambiguously that `u <a> <b> <c> ... i <verb>` means a, b, and c are all verb modifiers, while `u <a> <b> <c> ... a <noun>` means a, b, and c are all noun modifiers? Are there any cases where you would blend together noun *and* verb modifiers in some way, causing this system to break down? Specifically like in a more complex sentence? I haven't thought of any.

```
I quickly saw the super fast car drive recklessly.
```

That would become something like:

```
[a] me [u] quick [i] saw [u] the super fast [a] car [u] reckless [i] drive
```

So it seems you always have a sequence `<verb modifiers> <verb> <noun modifiers> <noun> <verb modifiers> <verb> etc.`

Comment: Terminology fix: What is called "determiner" in this question is not what usually named so in modern grammars. A modifier of an adverb may be  called *intensifier* but usually it is lumped  under the label *adverb* as well.

Comment: For determiners, look at this question on [linguistics.se]: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/12994/9781